# What does the notation 1{T = 1} mean?

Tags: notation, propensity-scores

Here's a screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

This is from [Evaluating Continuous Training Programs Using Generalized Propensity Scores](http://ftp.iza.org/dp3255.pdf) by Jochen Cluve, Hilmar Schneider, Arne Ulendorff and Zhong Zhao. I understand from the text that whether the treatment is at a value t is independent of the covariates X when the generalized propensity score at (t, X) is fixed. But the notation is unfamiliar. It's also in the [original GPS paper](http://scholar.harvard.edu/imbens/files/hir_07feb04.pdf).

What does it mean? What would **1**{T = t} mean? Was it invented specifically for describing GPS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is sometimes used for functions which are 1 when the argument is true and 0 otherwise.

Comment: I'd add that it is called an indicator function: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function

Comment: $I()$ is often used with the same meaning. Sometimes the argument is in brackets, sometimes in parentheses, sometimes as a subscript (which looks ugly and awkward in my view).  Donald Knuth and others have urged for decades that we should use notation in mathematics like $[T  = t]$ with this meaning. Hence $1()$ or $I()$ is dispensable. See e.g. http://arxiv.org/pdf/math/9205211.pdf In many programming languages something like `T == t` will be evaluated as 1 or 0: surrounding parentheses are often helpful and indeed prudent given precedence rules. Much here depends on your education!